# Blender arms are seetrough in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

So I'm trying to animate fps hands but the leather gloves models that I use are see through on one side. I've tried every tutorial but at this model I can't select the side to make it good in unity too.
The tutorial video that I tried: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9iV9wnvpQ1U.
The model that I use: https://gamebanana.com/models/4315.

Answer (score 0):

In blender, select the arms/arm > edit mode > face select mode > select all the faces on the object > mesh > normals > i think its render outside or face outside